# Generating all the possible values in a ndarray in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, game-theory, gambit

I am using gambit in python to simulate a world in a game theoretic manner. One construct of gambit is to save the "outcomes" for a set of decisions each player involved takes. This is of the form:

`game[d1,d2,d3,...,dn][n] = payoff`

where `d1` is the index of decision made by player 1, `d2` is the index of decision made by player 2, and so on and `n` is the index of the player for whom the `payoff` is being stored.

Now, there may be variable number of players, so the dimension of the index passed into the `game` object may change

how do I generate the series from `[0,0,...,0]` through `[8,8,...,8]` (where dimension = number of players = n) so that I can store them into `[d1,d2,d3,...,dn]`?

Comment: Not very clear what you need. Do you want to, individually, generate all combinations (permutations?) between [0,0,0,0,...] and [n,n,n,n,...], each with a length of `n`? Or do you just need an array of shape (n,n,n) to sore stuff in?  Can you show us a minimal example of the desired for two players? Is there a dimension for number of possible decisions?

Comment: @wwii I want to generate all permutations between [0,0,0,...,0] and [8,8,8,...,8] where the dimension (length?) of the indices is n. I have to do this based on some value of n dynamically.

Comment: How big is `n` likely to be? Unless `n` is quite small, the total number of combinations will chew up a lot of RAM. BTW, that kind of combination is called the cartesian product. In plain Python you'd generate it with `itertools.product`. There are various recipes for making cartesian products in Numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at python's `itertools` module.  It sounds like the `product` function will do what you want.

Example:

```
import itertools as it
 list(it.product(*[range(2)]*3))
```

Gives all lists of length three with two elements

```
[(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 1),
(0, 1, 0),
(0, 1, 1),
(1, 0, 0),
(1, 0, 1),
(1, 1, 0),
(1, 1, 1)]
```

There's lots of other possibilities with `itertools`, in particular it also provides `permutations` and `combinations`.